# Why is Colorama's Fore, Back and Style not working?

Tags: python, python-3.11, colorama, wordle-game

I am trying to create a wordle clone in python but it is not working. The problem is that the colours are not showing for some particular reason. Here is my code:

```
from colorama import Fore,Back,Style
import os
import random
import time
import sys
from typing import Final

WORD_LENGTH: Final = 5
GAME_LENGTH: Final = 6
ANSWERS_FILE_PATH: Final = r"Miscellaneous\Wordle\allWordleAnswers.txt"
ALLOWED_INPUT_WORDS_FILE_PATH: Final = r"Miscellaneous\Wordle\allWordleWords.txt"

def generateWord() -> str:
    with open(ANSWERS_FILE_PATH, "rt") as f:
        words = [word.strip() for word in f.readlines()]
        
    return random.choice(words)

def getInput(previousWords, word) -> str:
    with open(ALLOWED_INPUT_WORDS_FILE_PATH, "rt") as f:
        words = [word.strip() for word in f.readlines()]
        
    while True:
        inputted = input("What is going to be your next guess: ").lower()
        
        if len(inputted) != WORD_LENGTH:
            print("Your guess must be exactly 5 letters long.")
            continue
        
        if inputted not in words:
            os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")
            printWords(previousWords, word)
            print("Your guess was not an actual 5-letter word. Please try again.")
        else:
            os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")
            return inputted

def instructions():
    print("Wordle\n------")
    time.sleep(2.5)
    os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")
    
    print("White text means that letter does not appear in the correct word.\n")
    os.system("pause")
    os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")
    
    print(f"{Fore.YELLOW}Yellow text means that letter does appear in the correct word but in another spot.\n{Style.RESET_ALL}")
    os.system("pause")
    os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")
    
    print(f"{Fore.GREEN}Green text means that letter does appear in the correct word and that letter is also in the correct spot.\n{Style.RESET_ALL}")
    os.system("pause")
    os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")
    
def findColor(input_str, answer_str):
    if len(input_str) != WORD_LENGTH or len(answer_str) != WORD_LENGTH:
        raise ValueError("Both input and answer must be 5-letter strings")

    colors = []
    input_used = [False] * WORD_LENGTH
    answer_used = [False] * WORD_LENGTH

    for i in range(WORD_LENGTH):
        if input_str[i] == answer_str[i]:
            colors.append(Fore.GREEN)
            input_used[i] = True
            answer_used[i] = True
        else:
            colors.append(None)

    for i in range(WORD_LENGTH):
        if not input_used[i]:
            for j in range(WORD_LENGTH):
                if not answer_used[j] and input_str[i] == answer_str[j]:
                    colors[i] = Fore.WHITE
                    answer_used[j] = True
                    break
    
    for i in range(WORD_LENGTH):
        if colors[i] == None:
            colors[i] = Fore.WHITE
    
    return colors

def printWords(toPrintWords: list,comparer: str):    
    for index,word in enumerate(toPrintWords):
        colors: list = findColor(word,comparer)
        
        print(Back.BLACK)
        for color,letter in zip(colors,word): print(f"{color}{letter}",end = "")
        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
        
        if index == len(toPrintWords)-1: print("")

def main():
    os.system("cls" if os.name == "nt" else "clear")
    
    word: str = generateWord()
    previousWords: list = []
    
    instructions()
    
    while True:
        inputtedWord: str = getInput(previousWords,word)
        previousWords.append(inputtedWord)
        
        printWords(previousWords,word)
        
        if inputtedWord == word: 
            print(f"You won! You guessed the word \"{word}\" in {len(previousWords)} guesses!")
            sys.exit()
        elif len(previousWords) == GAME_LENGTH: 
            print(f"You lost. You couldn't guess the word \"{word}\" in time.") 
            sys.exit()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[It is showing no colour.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UymUA.png)

It is supposed to use colorama's fore, back and style to change the colours of the text but for some unknown reason it doesn't apply it.

Comment: Colorama is not magic that can directly tell Python to display coloured text - because **Python does not display the text**. All Colorama does is insert special characters that have a standard meaning according to the ANSI standard. It's up to the terminal to understand and implement this standard. It looks like you are trying to use the terminal output built in to Visual Studio Code. The linked duplicate is the best information we have for that. For future questions, please read [mre] and use **only the code necessary to demonstrate the problem** - not the overall task you are working on.

Comment: A useful way to debug the program's colour-inserting logic is to print into a file instead (open a file, and pass it as the `file` keyword argument to `print`), and check it with a text editor that clearly displays special control characters.